# Why is a solution lost after taking a variable power?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Specifically, I want to solve the following equation:
$$(89650)^{1-x} = 0.995\cdot(90000)^{1-x}+0.005\cdot(40000)^{1-x}$$

This yields 2 solutions, x = 0.9007 and x = 0.9375 (approx)

However, if I take the power of both sides of $\frac{1}{1-x}$, I get:
$$89650 = (0.995\cdot(90000)^{1-x}+0.005\cdot(40000)^{1-x})^{\frac{1}{1-x}}$$

By doing this, x = 0.9375 solution is lost. Why was the solution lost?

Also, I checked by inputting the following 2 equations in desmos:
$$y=0.995\cdot90000^{\left(1-x\right)}+0.005\cdot40000^{\left(1-x\right)}-89650^{\left(1-x\right)}$$
$$y=\left(0.995\cdot90000^{\left(1-x\right)}+0.005\cdot40000^{\left(1-x\right)}\right)^{\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)}-89650$$

I believe that this could be a problem with desmos, as wolfram alpha provided the expected solutions.

Comment: Why do you say the solution is "lost"?  How are you going about looking for it?  A solution to the first equation is certainly a solution to the second.

Comment: I graphed y=LHS-RHS on desmos, and it shows only one root on one of them, but 2 on the other.

Comment: If I substitute $x=.9375$ in the second equation, I get approximate equality, so it's either a glitch in Desmos, or you made a typo in the formula.  I did when I was checking the values.  I forgot to put parentheses around the exponent $\frac1{(1-x)}$.  I suggest you check that you didn't do something similar.

Comment: $x=0.9375\implies1-x=\frac{1}{16}$. Inserting this into the bottom equation gives roughly $89644$

Comment: Can you supply a link to your DESMOS work? That may make it more obvious what happened.

Comment: @Semiclassical Question updated with desmos work

Comment: For comparison, I get this in Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pbpjhq2ynd. There is indeed a root lost, but it's the root at $x=1$. (And losing this one makes sense, as you'd be raising both sides to the $1/(1-x)=\infty$ power.)

Comment: The true roots of the original function are easier to see in Desmos if you scale up the output so that you can more clearly see where it crosses the $x$ axis. See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nub2g2wwqb -- The roots at $1$ and near $0.9$ are easy to see, and it is also clear that there is no other root between them.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that you look for the zero of
$$f(x)=(89650)^{1-x} - 0.995\cdot(90000)^{1-x}-0.005\cdot(40000)^{1-x}$$ It varies too fast. Look instead at
$$g(x)=\log \left((89650)^{1-x} \right)-\log \left(0.995\cdot(90000)^{1-x}+0.005\cdot(40000)^{1-x} \right)$$ and plot it : it is much nicer and, beside the trivial $x=1$, there is a solution close to $0.9$.

Using Newton method to solve it, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.90000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 0.90070892824952277903 \\
 2 & 0.90071385413712372998 \\
 3 & 0.90071385437505765170 \\
 4 & 0.90071385437505765226
\end{array}
\right)$$